# Element inserted with innerHTML doesn't support scripts of the document

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, draggable

The scripts loaded in the document doesn't work on the injected code with innerHTML. I tried to put async or defer but nothing happened.

```
...
<script src="../scripts/traffic-lights.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/resizeable-windows.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/draggable-windows.js"></script>
<script>
const app = document.getElementById('app');
app.addEventListener("click", function() {addWindow("./app.html", "AppName")});

function addWindow(location, name) {
    const windows = document.createElement('section');
    windows.id = "window";
    windows.innerHTML = `
                      <div class="header" id="header">
                        <div class="traffic-lights" id="traffic-lights">
                          <button class="red" id="red"></button>
                          <button class="yellow" id="yellow"></button>
                          <button class="green" id="green"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="movable">
                          <div class="appname">${name}</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <iframe src=${location} width= "100%" height="100%" style="border:none;"></iframe>`
    document.body.appendChild(windows);
  }
</script>
```

Here the code for the script below:

- resizeable-windows.js

```
element = document.getElementById("window");
makeResizable(element, 400, 225, 10);
...
```

- draggable-windows.js

```
dragElement(document.getElementById("window"));

function dragElement(element) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById("movable")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById("movable").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
...
```

- traffic-lights.js

```
let trafficLights = document.getElementById("traffic-lights");
let redButton = document.getElementById("red");
let yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellow");
let greenButton = document.getElementById("green");
let windows = document.getElementById("window");

trafficLights.onmouseenter = function () { ...
```

Comment: You need a document-level event handler to catch dynamically added elements added after the handler was declared. in jquery, $(document).on('click', '#mynewelement', function() {/*do stuff*/});

Comment: Ok, and without the need of jQuery, how would you handled that ? I want to finish my project in Vanilla JavaScript then update with it with jQuery.

Comment: https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first 3 scripts, you query Elements (with `document.getElementById()`) which are not on the DOM yet (because they are added later dynamically by your `addWindow` function). Hence you actually get no Element.

As suggested by DeeGee and Kooilnc in the question comments, one of the possible solutions would be to use event delegation, attached on an already existing parent Element (typically the `document`, but could be `app` in your case).

Another possible solution would be to initialize your 3 scripts only once your `addWindow` function has inserted your Elements into the DOM:

- You can wrap their code in a function (1 per script file), that you execute inside `addWindow` after the DOM insertion:

```js
// traffic-lights.js
// Wrap the setup code with a function
function setupTrafficLights() {
  let trafficLights = document.getElementById("traffic-lights");

  trafficLights.onmouseenter = function () {}
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="../scripts/traffic-lights.js"></script>
<script>
  // ...

  function addWindow() {
    // ...
    // Insert into DOM
    document.body.appendChild(windows)

    // Now we can execute setup code that queries injected Elements into DOM
    setupTrafficLights()
  }
</script>
```

- You could also dynamically inject the 3 `<script>` tags.

Comment: Indeed I tried wrapping my script file into a function and it worked ! I was ready to set each windows hardcoded in the html with the visibility hidden, but thanks to stack overflow, your answer happens. Thank you !